# Adding Stripe Subscription to Blazor WASM

Tags: stripe-payments, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to add Stripe Subscription to my Blazor WASM Application following [these instructions](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/examples#usage-based-pricing) Since they are using JavaScript I am using the [JavaScript interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0). I added Stripe's script to my index.html and added a custom script with the javascript they have in the instructions.
Index.html inside the `<head>` tag

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script src="stripescript.js"></script>
```

stripescript.js:

```
let stripe = window.Stripe('MY PUBLIC KEY');
let elements = stripe.elements();

let card = elements.create('card', { style: style });
card.mount('#card-element');

card.on('change', function (event) {
    displayError(event);
});
function displayError(event) {
    changeLoadingStatePrices(false);
    let displayError = document.getElementById('card-element-errors');
    if (event.error) {
        displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
        displayError.textContent = '';
    }
}


function createPaymentMethod(cardElement, customerId, priceId) {
    return stripe
        .createPaymentMethod({
            type: 'card',
            card: cardElement,
        })
        .then((result) => {
            if (result.error) {
                displayError(error);
            } else {
                //change this to call .net
                createSubscription({
                    customerId: customerId,
                    paymentMethodId: result.paymentMethod.id,
                    priceId: priceId,
                });
            }
        });
}
```

My assumption is that the variable initializations would happen when the application is loaded. However, when I add the following HTML to my Razor page is not populating the card component.

```
<form id="payment-form">
    <div id="card-element">
        <!-- Elements will create input elements here -->
    </div>

    <!-- We'll put the error messages in this element -->
    <div id="card-element-errors" role="alert"></div>
    <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

I am lost on how to debug this, or if this is even possible in Blazor.

Comment: You have not shown code for the JsRuntime you are using to call the method to initialize, please update the question with all relevant code.

Comment: that is my question, since this is not in a function let stripe = window.Stripe('MY PUBLIC KEY');
let elements = stripe.elements();

let card = elements.create('card', { style: style });
card.mount('#card-element');  do I have to put it in a function and call it from there? or would it be automatically run since it is not in a function

Comment: Correct you need to put that in a function, and call that function from C# code on the page where you are loading it in.

Comment: if I put it in a function, is there a way to make the stripe variable available to other javascript functions? basically making it a global variable?

Comment: Basically, the code that initializes the stripe card element needs to be put in a method that will be called from c#. Other variables can be outside of the function so they are globally accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Umair's Comments, I realized that I had made a few mistakes and some of them were showing up in the console since I was trying to initialize the card element before the DOM was loaded. I was able to fix my problem by first changing the card mount into its own function. Here is the full stripescript.js for future people that have this problem:

```
let stripe = window.Stripe('MY KEY');
let elements = stripe.elements();
let style = {
    base: {
        fontSize: '16px',
        color: '#32325d',
        fontFamily:
            '-apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, sans-serif',
        fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
        '::placeholder': {
            color: '#a0aec0',
        },
    },
};
let card = elements.create('card', { style: style });

function mountCard() {
    card.mount('#card-element');
}

card.on('change', function (event) {
    displayError(event);
});
function displayError(event) {
    changeLoadingStatePrices(false);
    let displayError = document.getElementById('card-element-errors');
    if (event.error) {
        displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
        displayError.textContent = '';
    }
}


function createPaymentMethod(cardElement, customerId, priceId) {
    return stripe
        .createPaymentMethod({
            type: 'card',
            card: cardElement,
        })
        .then((result) => {
            if (result.error) {
                displayError(error);
            } else {
                //todo change this to call .net
                createSubscription({
                    customerId: customerId,
                    paymentMethodId: result.paymentMethod.id,
                    priceId: priceId,
                });
            }
        });
}
```

and added the following C# code to my Blazor component to render the card:

```
[Inject] IJSRuntime js { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("mountCard");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this on Youtube that is super complicated, and I decided to create my own implementation following KISS.

I have streamlined youtube's implementation on a single StripeCard component that interacts with my custom Js StripeInterop. I hope this makes your life easier.

This will allow you to have different publishable keys for your different environments without hardcoding it and reuse the component in multiple pages if you wish. Also, it will destroy itself when the component is used.

Here is my solution for **(blazor webassembly)**.

Add this to **index.html**

```
<!-- Stripe -->
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script src="stripescript.js"></script>
```

Here is **stripescript.js**

```
StripeInterop = (() => {
    var stripe = null;
    var elements = null;
    var dotNetReference = null;
    var card = null;

    var style = {
        base: {
            color: '#32325d',
            fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
            fontSize: '16px',
            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#aab7c4'
            }
        },
        invalid: {
            color: '#fa755a',
            iconColor: '#fa755a'
        }
    };
    
    return {
        init(dotnetHelper, publishableKey) {
            stripe = window.Stripe(publishableKey);
            elements = stripe.elements();

            card = elements.create('card', { style: style });
            dotNetReference = dotnetHelper;

            card.mount('#card-element');
            card.on('change', function (event) {
                displayError(event);
            });
        },
        createPaymentMethod(billingEmail, billingName) {
            return stripe
                .createPaymentMethod({
                    type: 'card',
                    card: card,
                    billing_details: {
                        name: billingName,
                        email: billingEmail
                    }
                })
                .then(function (result) {
                    if (result.error) {

                        displayError(result);
                        
                    } else {

                        dotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync('ProcessPaymentMethod', result.paymentMethod.id);
                    }
                });
        },
        destroy() {
            dotNetReference.dispose();
            card.destroy();
        }
    };

    function displayError(event) {

        var showError = document.getElementById('card-element-errors');

        if (event.error) {
            showError.textContent = event.error.message;
        } else {
            showError.textContent = '';
        }
    }
})();
```

Here is **StripeCard.razor** component

```
@namespace SmartApp.Components

<div id="card-element" style="display: block;
                              width: 100%;
                              padding: 0.52rem  .75rem;
                              font-size: 1rem;
                              line-height: 1.5;
                              color: #495057;
                              background-color: #fff;
                              background-clip: padding-box;
                              border: 1px solid #ced4da;
                              border-radius: .25rem;
                              transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;">
</div>
<div id="card-element-errors" class="validation-message"></div>
```

Here is **StripeCard.razor.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace SmartApp.Components
{
    public partial class StripeCard : IDisposable
    {
        [Inject] IJSRuntime JS { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public string PublishableKey { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> CardProcessedCallBack { get; set; }

        private bool _firstTime;

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            _firstTime = true;

            await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        }

        public async void Dispose()
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("StripeInterop.destroy");
        }

        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (_firstTime)
            {
                _firstTime = false;
                await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("StripeInterop.init", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this), PublishableKey);
            }
        }

        [JSInvokable("ProcessPaymentMethod")]
        public Task ProcessPaymentMethod(string paymentId)
        {
            return CardProcessedCallBack.InvokeAsync(paymentId);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how we use StripeCard.razor in our Page.

```
@page "/subscription/payment"

@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Organisation")]
@inject IJSRuntime JS


<div class="card card-custom card-shadowless rounded-top-0">
    <div class="card-body p-0">
        <div class="row justify-content-center py-8 px-8 py-lg-15 px-lg-10">
            <div class="col-xl-12 col-xxl-7">
                <!--begin: Wizard Form-->
                <EditForm Model="@_model" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit" >
                    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

                    <h4 class="mb-10 font-weight-bold text-dark">Enter your Payment Details</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-6">
                            <!--begin::Input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Name on Card</label>
                                <InputText @bind-Value="_model.BillingName" name="ccname" class="form-control form-control-solid form-control-lg"
                                           placeholder="Jane Doe" />
                                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _model.BillingName)" />
                            </div>
                            <!--end::Input-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xl-6">
                            <!--begin::Input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Notification Email</label>
                                <InputText @bind-Value="_model.BillingEmail" name="ccemail" class="form-control form-control-solid form-control-lg"
                                           placeholder="jane.doe@domain.com" />
                                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _model.BillingEmail)" />
                            </div>
                            <!--end::Input-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-12">
                            <!--begin::Input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Card Information</label>
                                <StripeCard PublishableKey="@_stripePublishableKey" CardProcessedCallBack="ProcessSubscriptionAsync"></StripeCard>
                                <span class="form-text text-muted">Powered by <strong>Stripe</strong>.</span>
                            </div>
                            <!--end::Input-->
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <ValidationSummary />

                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between border-top mt-5 pt-10">
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success font-weight-bolder text-uppercase px-9 py-4"
                                    @onclick="HandleValidSubmit">
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </EditForm>
                <!--end: Wizard Form-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



@code{

    private Model _model;
    private string _stripePublishableKey;

    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _model = new Model();
        _stripePublishableKey = "Here we put Development or Production publishableKey"; //Add publishable key here

        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("KTSubscriptionCheckout.init");
        }

        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("StripeInterop.createPaymentMethod", _model.BillingEmail, _model.BillingName);
    }

    //Callback method will return stripe paymentId
    private async Task ProcessSubscriptionAsync(string paymentId)
    {
        //We process paymentId here and continue with our backend process

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public class Model
    {
        [Required]
        public string BillingName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string BillingEmail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Youtube video if you want to have a look. https://youtu.be/ANYvFHHfyy8

Good luck...